# how to test a nodejs exports that contains async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, mocha.js

I am not sure how to test a nodejs's exports function. Consider the code below:

```
exports.create_expense = (req, res, next) ->
  User = database.db_model 'user'
  req.body.parsed_dt = Date.parse(req.body.date)
  req.body.amount = parseInt(req.body.amount)
  User.update {_id: req.api_session.id}, {$push: {expenses: req.body}}, (err, numberAffected, raw) ->
    if err?
      res.send 500
    else 
      res.send 200
```

`User` is a mongoose object here. I want to write a test (using mocha) to test this function (where in my test I will call `create_expense`)  but since `User.update` is async I can't just call `create_expense` without passing some form of Promise? I know I can use supertest but that also test the route which I dont want to do here. Is there any way to test this any npm here is useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `User.update` you should call `next`. And later in test you should call `done`.

**edit:**

Sorry for my CoffeeScript in advance.

Call `next` at the end of the callback to `User.update`.

Your test should look something like this then:

```
describe '#create_response', () ->
  response = false

  req.body.date = new Date
  req.body.amount = 123
  req.api_session.id = 'asd'

  res.send = (code) ->
    response = code

  it 'should return 500 on invalid request', (done) ->
    create_expense req, res, () ->
      assert.equal response, 500
      done
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The function response with a HTTP code it doesn't need to call next(). Are you suggesting that I should change the app code for the test? Do you have a example?

Comment: Pass in fake `req` and fake `res`. After sending response, call `next` (which should be some kind of callback). In `next` definition assert against fake `res` and finally call `done` (which should be passed in the test case by the framework).

Comment: Yes, you should write test first and then implement the code.

Comment: Great thank you. I was trying to see if there was another way without having to call next just for the test. Was use to that java have a way to 'weave' this sort of things with spies. Thanks again was great help! :)